# Flutter showModalBottomSheet update parent without Navigator.pop()

Tags: flutter, setstate, bottom-sheet, statefulwidget, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

In my app I would like to show a bottom sheet with `showModalBottomSheet` to let the user pick a font. When a new font is selected I would like to reflect the changes immediately in the parent view that is presenting the sheet without closing the sheet.

With `Navigator.pop(context, value);` I can easily send data back to the parent but I don't wanna close the bottom sheet on every selection.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

[image]

This it my current code to show and hide the picker modal:

**In the parent view.**

```
void showFontPicker() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        isDismissible: true,
        builder: (context) => FontPickerSheet()).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        widget.myPostcard.font = value;
      });
    });
}
```

**In the FontPickerSheet Widget:**

```
CupertinoPicker(
    itemExtent: 30,
    onSelectedItemChanged: (int value) {
       Navigator.pop(context, value);
    },
…
```

Comment: There are several ways, via a callback and a setState for example, or using a state manager like riverpod. Look at this example https://medium.com/@avnishnishad/flutter-working-with-callbacks-1d5e5f5d9c5a or riverpod https://riverpod.dev/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function to update the main state as parameter as follow:

**Parent view**

```
void showFontPicker() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        isDismissible: true,
        builder: (context) => FontPickerSheet(onSelected: updateMainView )).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        widget.myPostcard.font = value;
      });
    });
  }

  void updateMainView(value)
  {
    setState(() {
      widget.myPostcard.font = value
    });
  }
```

**FontPickerSheet Widget**

```
CupertinoPicker(
    itemExtent: 30,
    onSelectedItemChanged: (int value) {
       onSelected(value); // or widget.onSelected(value); [it depends on how you passed this value]
    },
…
```